# jQuery forEach() and change() function to hide a <select> and show an input

Tags: jquery

I have this form. I'm working in Laravel and the problem is when the user selects the option in `+10` it must to hide the `select` field and show the `input` field for each product in the shopping cart.

```
<td class="text-center">
    <form action="{{ route('cart.update') }}" method="POST" id="QtyRefresh">
    @csrf

    @if($detail->quantity >= 10)
        <input type="number" name="quantity2" class="inputQty" id="qtyInput2" value="{{ $detail->quantity }}" autofocus>
    @else
        <select name="quantity" id="qtySelect{{ $detail->id }}" class="selectQty">
            <option {{old('quantity',$detail->quantity)=="1"? 'selected':''}} value="1">1</option>
            <option {{old('quantity',$detail->quantity)=="2"? 'selected':''}} value="2">2</option>
            <option {{old('quantity',$detail->quantity)=="3"? 'selected':''}} value="3">3</option>
            <option {{old('quantity',$detail->quantity)>="10"? 'selected':''}} value="+10">+10</option>
        </select>
    @endif

    <input type="hidden" name="cart_detail_id" id="cartId{{ $detail->id }}" value="{{ $detail->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="qtyInput{{ $detail->id }}" class="inputQty" value="{{ $detail->quantity }}" autofocus>
</td>

<td id="tdQtyForm">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('QtyRefresh').submit()">
        <i class="material-icons" rel="tooltip" title="Actualizar Cantidad">refresh</i>
    </a>
</td>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var CartDetailId = '{{ $detail->id }}';
    var allSelect = document.querySelector("#CartTable").querySelectorAll("select");
    console.log(allSelect);

    allSelect.forEach(function(element){
        $(this).change(function()){
            if(element.value === '+10'){
                $('#qtySelect').remove();
                $('#qtyInput').attr('type', 'number').show().focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Image of the Table of Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PDS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `forEach()` and add event handlers to each individual select.  Both for performance, and simplicity, it is better to just add a single event handler which will match every `select`, and have it work out and target just the right elements.

Your question does not specify it but from the code it seems that you have a series of these sets of `select` inputs, each with a different `$detail->id`.  As your `select` and the hidden `input` you want to work with both use that ID value in their HTML ID attributes, we can use that to target the right elements.

[Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/mwo6k90d/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Handle changes on *every* select on the page
    $('select').on('change', function() {

        // Find the id of the select that was changed
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); 

        // Find the $detail->id of the select that was changed
        var detailID = id.replace('qtySelect', '');

        // Check the value selected
        if ($(this).val() === '+10') {

            // Show the input field with the matching $detail->id
            $('#qtyInput' + detailID).attr('type', 'number').show().focus();

            // Hide the select.  If you .remove() it, you can't re-display it 
            // if the user changes their selection back to 9 for example.
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Some notes:

- Your code is using a mix of pure JS and jQuery.  There is nothing technically wrong with that, but it certainly makes it harder to read and maintain.  If you are going to take the hit in including jQuery (extra http query, extra page load time, etc), and going to bother writing some jQuery code, you may as well use it, and make your code simpler and more consistent at the same time.
- It seems neater and simpler if your hidden input was just hidden with CSS, I mean it does not have to be a `type=hidden`.  Your JS is just changing presentation, that's what CSS is for.
- Likewise it might be better to simply hide the select, rather than outright `remove()` it, but this probably depends on your requirements.
- Lastly, for future reference, it will make it easier for others to help if you can try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In your case, the question is 100% about jQuery.  We don't need to see your Blade, PHP, Laravel stuff.  All we need is your **generated** HTML.  Similarly, `#qtyInput2` is not relevant, nor is `cart_detail_id`, nor is the refresh stuff .... The simpler you can state the problem, the simpler it is to read it, understand it, and answer it.